# I'm missing something in my Head to make the site responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm creating a responsive site with @media
So, I know that i'm missing some tag, some link in my Head
because when I enter in the website from my celphone its not responsive like is when I make the google chrome smaller in my PC.

Look at the head:

```
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="WordPress <?php bloginfo('version'); ?>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; <?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" title="RSS .92" href="<?php bloginfo('rss_url'); ?>" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Atom 0.3" href="<?php bloginfo('atom_url'); ?>" />  
    <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
```

Am I really missing something?

Comment: I guess viewport, https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Why don't you use a library like bootstrap or foundation? 
Foundation: http://foundation.zurb.com/ and 
Bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `<meta name="viewport"...` tag to tell devices to render the page correctly for their device independant pixels. Try something like:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; <?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
    <meta name="generator" content="WordPress <?php bloginfo('version'); ?>" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS 2.0" href="<?php bloginfo('rss2_url'); ?>" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/xml" title="RSS .92" href="<?php bloginfo('rss_url'); ?>" />
    <link rel="alternate" type="application/atom+xml" title="Atom 0.3" href="<?php bloginfo('atom_url'); ?>" />
```

`width=device-width` tells the page to match it's width to the device's width

`initial-scale=1.0` establishes a 1 to 1 relationship between the device's "device independent pixel" and CSS px pixels

Comment: i'll Try this =)
Thx for the fast message!